# Sharing code between dpkg scripts

Tags: package-management, dpkg

What is the standard way to share code between the dpkg scripts (preinst, postinst, prerm, postrm)?

I can see how to share code between just postinst and prerm (by installing it as part of the package), but can't see any way to share with preinst and postrm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing to be done. You can rely on a `Pre-Depend:`, but these are to be avoided unless absolutely necessary, as they're a heavy burden on the dependency chain.

You can pre-process the scripts, if there's code to be shared. The debhelper tools already do this, inserting boilerplate into the various maintainer scripts.

It's rare to need to do complicated things in `preinst` or `postinst`. The main adhockery tends to be handling tricky upgrades, and that's usually custom code in a `preinst`.

Comment: Pre-processing the scripts sounds like a reasonable option. Thanks.